# Script not working with STARTS WITH function in Qlik Sense

Tags: qlikview, qliksense, qlik-expression

I'm trying to load some tables using the script, in order to create new tables according to an IF condition.

My script is the following:

```
LOAD Pippo
if(color = 'green', 'ok',
if(color = 'yellow' and text <> 'No control needed', 'check',
if(color = 'red' and text <> 'Control now', 'check', 'ok'))) as Pippo1
```

In the line with the **color = yellow**, I want to catch different cases because there are many text occurrences starting with **'No control needed'** (for example No control needed (for 1 week), No control needed (for 2 weeks)), and I want to select them all.

I tried using: ****text<>'No control needed*'****, but it did not work.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Index()](https://help.qlik.com/en-US/qlikview/May2021/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/Scripting/StringFunctions/Index.htm) function can be used in this case.

`Index()` will search for `string-in-a-string` and if not found will return `0` else will return the position on which the searched string is found.

In your case this can be expressed as:

`Index(text, 'No control needed') = 0`

and the full expression:

```
LOAD 
Pippo,
if(color = 'green', 'ok',
if(color = 'yellow' and Index(text, 'No control needed') = 0, 'check',
if(color = 'red' and text <> 'Control now', 'check', 'ok'))) as Pippo1
```